# Exception Handling in PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, exception

I am new to the PHP laravel framework though I have used other PHP frameworks. I had written a cron where I had put some code in try..catch block but after few days of observation I came to realize that there have been runtime exceptions but the catch block was not executing.

I did some research and came across this documentation on Laravel's website -- https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/errors

From this page --

*The App\Exceptions\Handler class is where all exceptions triggered by your application are logged*

So, its good that all kinds of exceptions can be handled from one place but what if I don't want to do that? This makes things extremely generic. For an SQL exception thrown from anywhere in the system, this Handler class will execute a function. I would like to uniquely identify that some SQL exception was thrown from my process.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: Your `try { } catch()` block ***always*** execute before the global `App\Exceptions\Handler`. The centralised exception handler in Laravel only handles the exception that you don't catch, which indicates that your issue might be some place else?

Comment: In the try block, I am calling a model function, which is in a different file, if the exception arises in the model function, it should be routed to the calling try block, right?

Comment: Yep as long as you catch it correctly. Maybe paste in snippet of your code where you expect your exception to be `catch`-ed